# Curiosity on any Smartphones that Run on Android 2.3.3 with Different Screen Reoslution

Tags: libgdx, coordinates, resolution, screen, aspect-ratio

I have a question regarding about any smartphones that run only in *Android 2.3.3*. Is the size of screen or the screen resolution is always **HVGA** or does it have capable of running this OS (*Android 2.3.3*) on big screen size (**4" to 5"**) at about **720x1280**?

I'm thinking of the game's compatibility depending on the version of the Android OS and the screen resolution, which affects the change of coordinates especially for assigning touch buttons and drag-n-drop at exact location, before I'm gonna decide to make one. My program works on the Android 4 ICS and Jellybean, however, will that work on *Android 2.3.3* in spite of precise touch coordinate or just dependent on the screen resolution (regardless how large it is) as the X and Y coordinate?

And take note, I'm using Eclipse IDE for Java developers.

Comment: I have a prestigio pmp3384b tablet with Android 2.3.3 sporting 800x600 resolution. Not a smartphone but I think still relevant?

Comment: Yes it is, @Liosan. Since I gain more curiosity on this, I'll find out more how to fix bugs without getting worried about the app I've made that might affect between the old Android OS (2.3.3) and the latest one available (Android Jellybean). I'm still figure it out if the LibGDX endgine can still run smoothly even on the crispiest savvy 2D graphics and the coordinates for the buttons as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Android's rendering is OpenGL ES based, I can see absolutely no reason whatsoever why resolution should make any difference at all. The [Hexxeh Chromium Builds](http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/) run on any and all types of devices (netbooks, desktops, phones, whatever), so I cannot see how screen resolution can be an issue. Android is just a fuller featured branch of Chromium.

I have a Samsung Galaxy S (1, not 2 or 3) running 2.3.3 at 480×800, FWIW, in answer to the title of the question rather than the detail about higher resolutions.

Comment: One more thing before I accept your answer, @Nick Wiggill, does the OS itself, like Windows 7 for example, detects the size from minimum to maximum screen resolution depending on how big does the screen is (4" to 12")? Is it the same thing for Android OS or the OS itself provides available set of screen resolution variants and not from the screen size of the LCD screen?

Comment: @DavidDimalanta As far as I am aware, yes, the OS provides the interface to the hardware drivers via its windowing or general display subsystem. It queries the hardware and supplies that information to any querying applications. In the good old days, for desktops, I recall it was up to the application code to balance refresh rate against x and y resolution (someone can correct me if I'm wrong on that). This is not to say that Android/iOS are guaranteed to offer you more than one resolution, however. AFAIK, mobile phone resolutions are always fixed to one specific resolution and no other.

Comment: I see. For example, according to your perspective, lets say we have two smartphones with same screen size (5") and contain different Android OS: the first phone contains 2.3.3 while the other phone is Android 4 ICS. So, even if two smartphones have different OS versions, the screen resolution is still the same, right? And even if you compare with the smaller screen, the screen resolution is still the same, right?

Comment: @DavidDimalanta Have you ever tried setting any LCD monitor to a resolution that it doesn't match up with? Have you noted the artifacting effect this causes? Now consider the average mobile phone screen. Very small, and it presents very fine detail indeed. Artifacting is not an option. The resolution _has to_ be fixed. The only viable alternatives, at that scale, to maximum resolution would be pixel-doubled resolutions. Google 'smartphone "fixed resolution" ' or 'amoled "fixed resolution" '. Lastly, refer to the [wikipedia article on the topic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_resolution).

Comment: Pixel perfect? You mean that if the image, especially the circles and triangles, fit right on that screen, then this fits right and no distortions? However, it should be proportional depending on the screen. If you say "fixed resolution," meaning that the screen resolution of the device itself will be its final size of it?

Comment: @DavidDimalanta You are referring to OpenGL rendering via LibGDX. Look at [this diagram of clip/screen space](http://antongerdelan.net/opengl/index.php?title=Overlays). You can see how we run from -1 to 1 in each axis. Unless you have a square screen, you must do your own perspective and viewport correct transformations, or else you will experience the stretching problem. It is left up to client code to do this; OpenGL uses a -1 to 1 coordinate system specifically because OpenGL is completely device/platform agnostic i.e. it doesn't care. Open a new question to ask _how_ you do that.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your help, @Nick Wiggil. It's up to the codes to do the talk for the adjustments. Until then.